# Execute file with external program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I find it strange that I couldn't find an answer to this question. Maybe I searched the wrong keywords but all I could find was about reading files.

I have a string with the pathname of a video file. On clicking of a button I want to open/run this file with its default video player. The rest of my program should be unchanged and still responsive. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is very platform-dependent.

Comment: It is operating system specific. For Linux, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has several chapters about your question. Consider [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) + [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: On windows - `ShellExecute()` with the "open" verb

Comment: Don't use "open", use `nullptr`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Or `NULL` for non-C++11 compilers.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you call either `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx`. Supply a verb and the filename. You can use `"open"` as the verb, or `nullptr`. If you opt for the latter then the default verb will be used.

As for which function to call, `ShellExecute` is simpler to call but has less functionality. The key functionality that it is missing is sane reporting of errors. For that reason I'd recommend `ShellExecuteEx`.

This MSDN article has some example code: [Launching Applications (ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx, SHELLEXECUTEINFO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886.aspx). That article, and the function documentation should be enough.

Comment: You say supply "open" and the filename but `ShellExecute("open", objectPtr->getPathname());` doesn't work. What exactly are the parameters for the ShellExecute?

Comment: This function is well documented. A websearch will take you to the documentation. That's a skill that you should learn. If you'd followed the link in my answer, you'd have found out too. I suggest that you need to slow down a little and read the documentation very carefully. That's always wise when you start calling a new API.

Comment: So you won't give me an answer to my question because "This function is well documented"? Honestly, I looked at the linked example and I don't understand it at all. `ShellExecute(hwnd, "find", "c:\\MyPrograms", NULL, NULL, 0);` Is the only part that makes a bit of sense but still I have no idea what hwnd is and there is no mention of it anywhere in the documentation. I just want to achieve the basic task of opening a file. I don't care about error checking and all that other stuff in my example.

Comment: You read the documentation for `ShellExecute` and `ShellExecuteEx` right? Have you used the Win32 API before?

Comment: Next you should read the documentation of the two functions. Start with `ShellExecute` because it is easier. If you've never programmed Win32 before then you are more likely to have success with `ShellExecute`.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't answer my question but instead just link me to documentations which I don't understand at all. The program where I am trying to implement this does a lot and opening a video file is almost a trivial part of it. I don't need to know about Win32 API or the full capabilities of this function just now. If I ever have to work on a program where `ShellExecute` plays a bigger part in then I will wrap my head around its documentation. But at the moment, being still fairly new to C++, I have no idea what I am looking at.

Comment: I did come up with this `ShellExecute(NULL, LPCTSTR("open"), LPCTSTR(ObjectPtr->getPathname()), NULL, NULL, 0);` but this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Well, your casts look dubious. You are passing `SW_HIDE` for the final parameter. You should pass `SW_SHOWNORMAL`. Sadly the MSDN doc that I linked to has led you astray. I've no idea what `ObjectPtr->getPathname()` is. If you have to cast it, then probably it isn't the right type, and the cast won't help. Pass `"open"` for the verb. If that doesn't work, pass `L"open"`, a UTF-16 string. If that compiles then my guess is that `ObjectPtr->getPathname()` is a `const char*`. And perhaps you need to start using Unicode, or call `ShellExecuteA`.

Comment: There's a pretty steep learning curve here. You next need to get on top of old school C strings, and ANSI vs UTF-16 in the Win32 API. As for why I won't write your code for you, how can I? You did not tell me what `ObjectPtr->getPathname()` is. If I don't know what that is, how can I write your code for you. It looks like you don't want to learn. I think your expectations are wrong.